# Spark Streaming Flume Integration

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, flume

After trying many changes, I'm still stuck with a problem of binding the Flume custom sink and Spark Stream together to the same port.  I'm using Flume 1.6.0 and Spark 2.0.0. 
Using the Spark+flume Integrations guide I built the .conf file and the spark .py file. I first start the flume agent , but then when I try using Spark-streaming on the same port(to read), it says fail to bind. I've tried Multiple ports, and to my knowledge couldn't find any network restrictions(full privilege). Im running both of them on the same local server. 
Do any of you know how to tackle this problem ?
Would Appreciate any help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/streaming-flume-integration.html) and if you still run into issues , share your configuration file and streaming code.

Your configuration file should look like below.

```
 agent.sinks = spark
 agent.sinks.spark.type = org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.sink.SparkSink
 agent.sinks.spark.hostname = <hostname of the local machine>
 agent.sinks.spark.port = <port to listen on for connection from Spark>
 agent.sinks.spark.channel = memoryChannel
```

You streaming code should be as below

```
 from pyspark.streaming.flume import FlumeUtils
 addresses = [([sink machine hostname 1], [sink port 1]), ([sink machine hostname 2], [sink port 2])]
 flumeStream = FlumeUtils.createPollingStream(streamingContext, addresses)
```